# Javafx click on a Circle and get it's reference

Tags: java, javafx

I have a set of Nodes, Circles, on the stage.
I want to be able to click on one of them and 'select it' (just get a reference to it so I can move it around, change color etc.)

```
    Pane root = new Pane();
    root.getChildren().addAll( /* an array of Circle objects */ );

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500, BACKGROUND_COLOR);

    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            // how do I get which Circle I clicked on?
        }
    });

    stage.setTitle(TITLE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

Comment: Why not have an array of Circle objects, and add those to the Scene? And then get the X and Y position of the mouse, and then check if any of the Circle contains that Point. If it does, then that circle is clicked.

Comment: @Steven One possible solution. My array would be 15k in length though. So I was wondering if there is a smarted solution

Comment: could you store all the X,Y positions of all circles in a different array, and return the index of the Circle Array that equals (X[i] == xMouse) && (Y[i] == yMouse)? I'm not too sure what would be more efficient.

Comment: @Steven Well problem is that circles have a radius, so you could click off centre and you'd have no way of knowing where unless you calculate to check if it is within the circle or not. 1/2

Comment: @Steve I understand where you're coming from and what you're thinking is. But my hope was to find some javafx builtin functionality that could return exactly the Circle that was click on (like a button click, but with a circle) 2/2

Comment: True, good luck. Sorry I couldn't be more of a help.

Comment: Typically you would add an event handler to each circle, not to the container containing the circle. Then the circle that was clicked is simply the circle to which you added  the listener. I don't think this introduces any performance issues, even with a very large array of circles; the event handler has minimal state, especially compared to that of the circle itself. (That said: 15K circles? Perhaps there is just a better solution for whatever it is you're trying to do...)

Comment: @James_D Its a map application, where each circle represents an intersection. I am using a 'camera' to limit drawing to only those in view, but still it means hundreds of circles at any given time.

Comment: So I would definitely just register a handler with each circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply register a listener with each circle itself. Then you already have the reference to the circle with which the listener was registered.

This example pushes the limit a little as to usability, because it has 10,000 circles shown all at once, but it demonstrates the technique:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GridOfCircles extends Application {

    private static final PseudoClass SELECTED_P_C = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");

    private final int numColumns = 100 ;
    private final int numRows = 100 ;
    private final double radius = 4 ;
    private final double spacing = 2 ;

    private final ObjectProperty<Circle> selectedCircle = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(); 

    private final ObjectProperty<Point2D> selectedLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        selectedCircle.addListener((obs, oldSelection, newSelection) -> {
            if (oldSelection != null) {
                oldSelection.pseudoClassStateChanged(SELECTED_P_C, false);
            }
            if (newSelection != null) {
                newSelection.pseudoClassStateChanged(SELECTED_P_C, true);
            }
        });

        Pane grid = new Pane();

        for (int x = 0 ; x < numColumns; x++) {
            double gridX = x*(spacing + radius + radius) + spacing ;
            grid.getChildren().add(new Line(gridX, 0, gridX, numRows*(spacing + radius + radius)));
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < numRows ; y++) {
            double gridY = y*(spacing + radius + radius) + spacing ;
            grid.getChildren().add(new Line(0, gridY, numColumns*(spacing + radius + radius), gridY));
        }

        for (int x = 0 ; x < numColumns; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ;y < numRows ; y++) {
                grid.getChildren().add(createCircle(x, y));
            }
        }


        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            Point2D loc = selectedLocation.get();
            if (loc == null) {
                return "" ;
            }
            return String.format("Location: [%.0f, %.0f]", loc.getX(), loc.getY());
        }, selectedLocation));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(new ScrollPane(grid));
        root.setTop(label);


        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("grid.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Circle createCircle(int x, int y) {
        Circle circle = new Circle();
        circle.getStyleClass().add("intersection");
        circle.setCenterX(x * (spacing + radius + radius) + spacing);
        circle.setCenterY(y * (spacing + radius + radius) + spacing);
        circle.setRadius(radius);

        circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> {
            selectedCircle.set(circle);
            selectedLocation.set(new Point2D(x, y));
        });

        return circle ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

with the file grid.css:

```css
.intersection {
    -fx-fill: blue ;
}
.intersection:selected {
    -fx-fill: gold ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the reference by using [getSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html?is-external=true#getSource--) of the [MouseEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html).

Example in which you can drag a Circle and any other Node:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Circle circle = new Circle( 100,100,50);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        circle.setFill(Color.BLUE.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle( 0,0,100,100);
        rectangle.relocate(200, 200);
        rectangle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        rectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.3));

        Text text = new Text( "Example Text");
        text.relocate(300, 300);

        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(circle, rectangle, text);

        MouseGestures mouseGestures = new MouseGestures();
        mouseGestures.makeDraggable(circle);
        mouseGestures.makeDraggable(rectangle);
        mouseGestures.makeDraggable(text);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static class MouseGestures {

        class DragContext {
            double x;
            double y;
        }

        DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();

        public void makeDraggable( Node node) {

            node.setOnMousePressed( onMousePressedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseDragged( onMouseDraggedEventHandler);
            node.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

        }

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = event -> {

            if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                Circle circle = (Circle) (event.getSource());

                dragContext.x = circle.getCenterX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = circle.getCenterY() - event.getSceneY();

            } else {

                Node node = (Node) (event.getSource());

                dragContext.x = node.getTranslateX() - event.getSceneX();
                dragContext.y = node.getTranslateY() - event.getSceneY();

            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = event -> {

            if( event.getSource() instanceof Circle) {

                Circle circle = (Circle) (event.getSource());

                circle.setCenterX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                circle.setCenterY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

            } else {

                Node node = (Node) (event.getSource());

                node.setTranslateX( dragContext.x + event.getSceneX());
                node.setTranslateY( dragContext.y + event.getSceneY());

            }

        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = event -> {
        };

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```