# How to identify objects with the same variable name in javaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, polygon, eventhandler

We want to make an application where the user can make different polygons on the scene and afterwards the program lets the user identify these polygons by clicking on them. The polygons are made in this part of the code:

```
private boolean draw = true;
private Polugon polygon;
private Group root;
private List<Double> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
int polygonId = 0;
private EventHandler<MouseEvent> polygonDrawer = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && draw) { //if the user clicks on the scene twice the polygon-drawing is finished
            draw = false;
            polygonId ++; //every polygon has its own ID
            coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            draw = true;
            coordinates.add(mouseEvent.getX());
            coordinates.add(mouseEvent.getY());
            polygon = new Polugon(polygonId);
            polygon.getPoints().addAll(coordinates);
            root.getChildren().add(polygon);
        }
    }
};
```

Class Polugon:

```
public class Polugon extends Polygon{
    private int id;

    public Polugon(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Polygon ID " + id;
    }
//there are other methods
}
```

We have tried to make an EventHandler that would print out the ID of a polygon when it is clicked on, but it always returns the ID of the last polygon that has been drawn. For further information: we have ToggleButtons for drawing a polygon and getting the ID of the polygon on the scene.

**How to identify these polygons if they have the same variable names?**

Comment: And where is that attempt to add a handler to the `Pogulon`?

Comment: Actually I just found the solution from this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026042/javafx-click-on-a-circle-and-get-its-reference). I created a List to store polygons and then looped the list to find if polygon contains the mouse x, y position.

Comment: @RistoYlem The solutions to the question you linked do nothing like what you describe. Why don't you use the solutions provided there?